# Count lines in a file

Tags: python, perl

I have a text file that consists of million of vectors like this:-

```
V1
V1
V1
V3
V4
V1
V1
```

Note:- ORDER is important. In the above output file, i counted the first vector 3 times. The same pattern is repeated twice after 5th line. There count should be different.

I want to count how many times each vector line is repeated and add it in the output text file like this:-

In above 7 vectors, first 3 lines are same and rest 2 are different and then last lines are same. So the output should look like this:-

```
V1 count 3
V3
V4
V1 count 2
```

Although, first and last patterns are same but they are counted differently because they are in different order.

I can use `python` or `perl`.I know the maximum length of rows (vectors) but how do I compare each row (vector) with other. Please help

Comment: I used SAS coding language but it is not best way. it is time consuming and long code. I need some simple way.

Comment: This is not generated from ATE.

Comment: Do you want that exact output format? My answer is the only one that gives it.

Comment: Does the output order of lines matter?  Several of the Python solutions lose order information.

Comment: yes, order matters to me. Go from the first line until the last line.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com), [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## If order doesn't matter

If you really want to do this in python (as opposed to the `sort filepath | uniq -c` as Jean suggests), then I would do this:

```
import collections
with open('path/to/file') as f:
    counts = collections.Counter(f)
    outfile = open('path/to/outfile', 'w')
    for line,occ in counts.iteritems():
        outfile.write("%s repeat %d\n" %(line.strip(), occ))
    outfile.close()
```

## If order matters

If order matters (if entry `i` appears before entry `j` in the input file, then entry `i` must appear before entry `j` in the output file), then what you need is a modified run-length encoder. Note however, if you have the following input file:

```
v1
v1
v1
v2
v2
v3
v1
```

then, your output file will look like this:

```
v1 repeat 3
v2 repeat 2
v3
v1

with open('infilepath') as infile:
    outfile = open('outfilepath', 'w')
    curr = infile.readline().strip()
    count = 1
    for line in infile:
        if line.strip() == curr:
            count += 1
        else:
            outfile.write(curr)
            if count-1:
                outfile.write(" repeat %d\n" %count)
            else:
                outfile.write("\n")
            curr = line.strip()
            count = 1
    outfile.write(curr)
    if count-1:
        outfile.write(" repeat %d\n" %count)
    outfile.close()
```

Of course, `uniq -c infilepath > outfilepath` will do the same

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm getting an error- File not open for writing. I also added "import collections" at the top to run it.

Comment: @SudhaVerma: Sorry about the error. I fixed the typo that caused it. Yes, you would have to import collections (reflected in the changes)

Comment: also this will only work on py27 or higher ... (which I assume is fine... since you can run it, but none the less is something to be aware of)

Comment: The OP mentioned in the comments to the question that order is important, so I think `Counter`-based approaches may not work.

Comment: Edited to include order-preserving mechanism

Comment: please see the chnages in the questions. The order matters.

Comment: the above explanation -v1, v2...is exactly same as I'm looking into.

Comment: @SudhaVerma: I edited my question with an order-preserving answer 4 minutes before you called my attention to the change in your question

Comment: @SudhaVerma: based on your most recent edit, my second solution does EXACTLY what you want

Comment: @ikegami: `count` is never set to `0` or decremented and is only ever set to `1` and incremented. adding an `if count` check would be redundant

Comment: You have an unconditional `outfile.write(curr)`. That's wrong. ...or actually, without the \n, I guess that is right. Nevermind.

Comment: There is one problem in the above script. It is not printing the last line count. When i used the "uniq -c infilepath > outfilepath ", it gives me the last line with count .

Comment: Oh, you fixed it with changes in the script. The extra block in the end is now counting the last line as well.

Comment: Can we add (;) semicolon at each end of line?

Comment: @SudhaVerma: There's no point to ending lines of python code with `;`s, although doing so is not syntactically wrong. Adding a `;` at the end of each line in the input (or the subsequent output) though, does not require a change in code

Comment: @SudhaVerma: if you want to add a `;` after `count n`, this can be done by adding a `;` in the corresponding `write` statements

Answer (score 4):

```
perl -nle'
   if ($c && $_ ne $last) {
      print $c > 1 ? "$last repeat$c;" : "$last;";
      $c = 0;
   }

   $last = $_;
   ++$c;

   END {
      if ($c) {
         print $c > 1 ? "$last repeat$c;" : "$last;";
      }
   }
' file
```

(You can put that all on one line, or leave it as is.)

Output:

```
V1 repeat3
V3
V4
V1 repeat2
```

This solution is avg case O(N) CPU and O(1) memory. It and inspectorG4dget's are the only two of the seven existing answers that give the output in the format and order you requested.

Comment: Changed solution so it preserves order.

Comment: Updated to the new specs (only combine consecutive repeating lines).

Comment: The last if (which you have repeated btw), is redundant, as $c can never be 0 there.

Comment: That's true, but you still have two `if`s. One regular, one post-script.

Comment: Not quite sure I follow. `if ($c) { print if $c }` if $c is false, the block is never called, if $c is true, the post-script `if` can never be false. ETA: I'm only talking about the ifs in the END block.

Comment: @TLP, oh, there are *three* ifs. Fixing.

Comment: Can we add (;) semicolon at each end of line?

Comment: Do you mean each line of code or each line of output? I'm going to assume you mean the latter. Done.

Answer (score 2):

Just run this on command prompt

```
sort text.txt | uniq -c > output.txt
```

Remove sort if you want to preserve ordering(Will only count consecutive unique lines)

```
uniq -c text.txt > output.txt
```

Or this will give the required precise output(Solution suggested by ikegami)

```
uniq -c text.txt \
| perl -ple's/^\s*(\d+) //; $_ .= " repeat$1" if $1 > 1; \
> output.txt
```

Comment: Fixed to give requested output.

Answer (score 0):

I dont htink  you can do this in less than O(n^2) ...  (I could be wrong)

one way would be (in python)

```
with open("some_file_with_vectors") as f:
          data = f.read()

counts  = dict([(line,data.count(line)) for line in data.splitlines()])
print counts
#if you want to save to a file
with open("output.txt") as f:
   for key in counts:
       print >> f, key ,"=",counts[key]
```

Comment: no ... data.count(elem) is O(N) ... so therefor it is O(n^2) ... unless im mistaken ... (but thanks for the faith in me bein a super coder :P)

Comment: It doesn't print anything. Can we store the output in text file?

Comment: Ok, I don't know Python. Didn't know that data.count is O(N). See my answer for an O(N) version.

Comment: it does print for me with your example set ... I get {'10000000000000000000XXXXXXXXXXXX000XXXXXXXXXXXXX1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX': 1, '00000000000000000000XXXXXXXXXXXX000XXXXXXXXXXXXX1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX': 3, '01000000000000000000XXXXXXXXXXXX000XXXXXXXXXXXXX1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX': 1}

Answer (score 0):

If it all fits into memory, then you could do:

```
from collections import Counter

with open('vectors') as fin:
    counts = Counter(fin)
```

Or, if large, then you can use sqlite3:

```
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.conncet('/some/path/some/file.db')
db.execute('create table vector (vector)')
with open('vectors.txt') as fin:
    db.executemany('insert into vector values(?)', fin)
    db.commit()

for row in db.execute('select vector, count(*) as freq from vector group by vector'):
    print row # do something suitable here
```

If the vectors are always contiguous:

```
from itertools import groupby
with open('vector') as fin:
    for vector, vals in groupby(fin):
        print '{} {}repeat'.format(vector, sum(1 for _ in vals))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming python 2.7, a less memory-intensive solution

```
from collections import Counter
with open("some_file.txt") as f:
    cnt = Counter(f)
    print cnt
```

Comment: I think this still ends up O(N^2)  ... im pretty sure it always will be ... counter is N^2 complexity afaik  (since I dont have py2.7 im not positive ... but I cant see any way it would not be n^2)

Comment: @JoranBeasley: why would Counter be O(N^2)?   You're just looping over each line (O(N)), checking to see if you've seen it already (O(1), basically, because of the hash), and incrementing/setting to 0 the current value (also ~O(1)).

Comment: @JoranBeasley, a Counter is a dictionary under the hood, which should imply time complexity is amortized O(1), no?

Comment: oh thanks DSM .. that actually makes good sense ...

Comment: @cravoori, "dictionary" is not a data structure. It's just another way of saying "associative array". The complexity depends on the actual data structure.

Comment: @ikegami, agreed, i meant the hash table impl underlying the python dictionary but your point is taken

Answer (score 0):

```
vectors = {}
for vector in open("vect.txt").readlines():
    vectors[vector] = vectors.setdefault(vector, 0) + 1
print vectors
```

Comment: Please add some explanation, not just code.